# VPN Connects but cannot access remote network computers or folders

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I am connecting to a remote network via Windows 10 VPN. I can make the connection but cannot access the remote's local network even though I have allowed access on the Server's Incoming setting. The login account has read/write permissions to the local shares.

Both Remote and Client have different local IPs

Client - from 200.200.200.1

Server - from 192.168.1.1

The VPN assigns the IPs between 2.2.2.1 to 2.2.2.10

On Connection, the Server gets the IP 2.2.2.2 while the Client has the IP 2.2.2.8

Typing in \\2.2.2.2\My Documents into the Explorer Window gets "Windows Cannot access \\2.2.2.2\My Documents"

SMB is enabled on both machines.

I can Remote Desktop between both machines.

1723 is forwarded.

I am unable to access the folders/files either on the lan or wan through VPN but I can access the folders via the local neighborhood network.

Comment: Did you enable a subnet-wide mask on your network (255.255.255.0) ?

Comment: The subnet on both machines is 255.255.255.0 but the VPN's subnet is 255.255.255.255. Do I need to change the VPN's 255.255.255.255 to 255.255.255.0? I see no option in the Incoming Connection setting.

Comment: Try addressing the folder resources by IP address.  I am not sure what you mean be VPN subnet.  In the VPN remote group settings, it should allow all addresses.  So I think you need to change this based on your description.

Comment: Do you mean by the VPN's assigned IP \\2.2.2.2\? because I tried that also tried the Public IP. When connected to the remote computer, in network connection I see the client connected. In the Status box it states IPv4 and IPv6 Connectivity as "Not Connected", Media State "Connected".

Comment: I am not sure. In my VPN (IPsec), security and basic VPN connection has to succeed before folders can be mapped. So I am not certain here.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this video for the solution

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOG-UlXNmDw

Things to do:

1. Make sure that the VPN Server's IP assignment is within the DHCP Pool. I was using from 2.2.2.1 when I should have used from 192.168.1.1 (eg 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.59)
2. Allow UDP 1723 in the Inbound rules of Windows Firewall
3. Also in the Inbound Rules, the Public Profile for "File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)", in the Scope Tab add "Internet" to the Remote IP Addresses.